# ¿Cuál es la diferencia entre un Tibble y un DataFrame?

Tags: r, rstudio

estoy aprendiendo R y tengo una duda, en el curso que estoy tomando muestran diversos paquetes de tidyverse, y noté que al trabajar data sets una de las diferencias principales es que por ejemplo, las funciones para combinar ya sea join o bind producen un "data frame" que en el retorno dice "A tibble: [dimensiones]" y al revisar su clase, es un data frame, y en otras ocasiones no retorna eso. Alguien me podría explicar si son lo mismo o si hay alguna diferencia?
[image: Sin mensaje de tibble]

[image: Con mensaje de tibble]

Answer (score 6, accepted):

## `data.frame`

El `data.frame` es una de las estructuras de datos básicas de R, forma parte de la librería `base::` y por lo tanto está disponible en cualquier instalación de R, sin requerir paquetería adicional.

Se trata de una estructura tabular, es decir, organizada en filas y columnas. Además de los datos que están en esas filas y columnas un data.frame tiene dos atributos (metadatos): los nombres de columna, que se consultan o modifican con `colnames(df)` y los nombres de filas, a los que accedemos con `rownames(df)`.

## `tibble`

Un `tibble`  es una estructura de datos muy similar a un data.frame (rectangular, organizada en filas y columnas) disponible en el paquete `tibble` y por lo tanto en el `tidyverse`. Estructuralmente un `tibble` es también un `data.frame`, por eso cuando preguntas por la clase del objeto te regresa los dos valores. Sin embargo hay tres pequeñas diferencias:

## Diferencias

1. El método `print` de los `data.frame` y de los `tibble` es diferente. Por eso cuando muestras en consola uno u otro se ven resultados diferentes. No es que sean diferentes los datos, solo cambia el método para mostrarlos. Personalmente prefiero el método de los `tibble`, que aprovecha mejor el espacio en pantalla y muestra más información o información más relevante. Es la razón más fuerte para usarlos.
2. Si bien los `tibble` pueden utilizar `rownames` por defecto los eliminan y se desaconseja usar ese atributo. Esto para mejorar la compatibilidad con datos provenientes una base de datos `SQL`, en los que los nombres de fila no tienen sentido.

<s>3. Por defecto no convierte a las cadenas de caracteres (strings) en factores. Esto es buena idea, los factores son un tipo de datos complicado de mantener y manipular y es buena práctica mantenerlos como cadenas de caracteres hasta último momento, cuando no queda otra alternativa que usarlos.</s>

> A partir de R 4.0 en el data.frame ya no crea factores a partir de cadenas como opción de por defecto.

Por defecto la mayoría de las funciones del `tidyverse` crean objetos `tibble`, aunque siguen siendo compatibles con los `data.frame` dada la gran familiaridad entre unos y otros. Sin embargo este comportamiento no es completamente consistente y algunas funciones o en algunos casos se producen `data.frame` cuando se esperaría un `tibble`. Esto no es un problema grave, ya que son estructuras prácticamente intercambiables, aunque puede ser peligroso si estás creando un programa que va a funcionar sin supervisión y requieres certidumbre sobre los tipos y estructuras de datos que se van creando. En uso interactivo es solamente algo molesto.

## Cambiar de `tibble` a `data.frame` (y vice versa)

En cualquier momento puedes pasar un `tibble` a un `data.frame` con la función `as.data.frame()`. A la inversa, puedes pasar cualquier data.frame a tibble con `as_tibble()`, prestando atención a lo que ocurra con los `rownames()`.

## Funciones que dan error con `tibble`

Con algunas funciones que reciben como input a una `data.frame` a veces obtenemos un error si les suministramos un `tibble` ¿Por qué, si son iguales? Porque seguramente esa función hace una verificación de la clase del objeto input comparando solamente el primer elementos de la lista `class()`. Como muestras en tu segundo bloque de código la clase `data.frame` aparece en el tercer lugar y entonces esta función no lo encuentra y se ejecuta el `else` de la verificación. En esos casos puedes coercionar el `tibble` a `data.frame` y asunto resuelto.

Comment: Muchas gracias!